# python lambda as callback

Tags: python, lambda

I have been reading example of astersik ARI in python and could not understand the following code clearly
full sample code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""Example demonstrating ARI channel origination.
"""

#
# Copyright (c) 2013, Digium, Inc.
#
import requests

import ari

from requests import HTTPError

OUTGOING_ENDPOINT = "SIP/blink"

client = ari.connect('http://localhost:8088/', 'hey', 'peekaboo')

#
# Find (or create) a holding bridge.
#
bridges = [b for b in client.bridges.list()
           if b.json['bridge_type'] == 'holding']
if bridges:
    holding_bridge = bridges[0]
    print "Using bridge %s" % holding_bridge.id
else:
    holding_bridge = client.bridges.create(type='holding')
    print "Created bridge %s" % holding_bridge.id


def safe_hangup(channel):
    """Hangup a channel, ignoring 404 errors.
    :param channel: Channel to hangup.
    """
    try:
        channel.hangup()
    except HTTPError as e:
        # Ignore 404's, since channels can go away before we get to them
        if e.response.status_code != requests.codes.not_found:
            raise


def on_start(incoming, event):
    """Callback for StasisStart events.
    When an incoming channel starts, put it in the holding bridge and
    originate a channel to connect to it. When that channel answers, create a
    bridge and put both of them into it.
    :param incoming:
    :param event:
    """
    # Only process channels with the 'incoming' argument
    if event['args'] != ['incoming']:
        return

    # Answer and put in the holding bridge
    incoming.answer()
    incoming.play(media="sound:pls-wait-connect-call")
    holding_bridge.addChannel(channel=incoming.id)

    # Originate the outgoing channel
    outgoing = client.channels.originate(
        endpoint=OUTGOING_ENDPOINT, app="hello", appArgs="dialed")

    # If the incoming channel ends, hangup the outgoing channel
    incoming.on_event('StasisEnd', lambda *args: safe_hangup(outgoing))
    # and vice versa. If the endpoint rejects the call, it is destroyed
    # without entering Stasis()
    outgoing.on_event('ChannelDestroyed',
                      lambda *args: safe_hangup(incoming))

    def outgoing_on_start(channel, event):
        """Callback for StasisStart events on the outgoing channel
        :param channel: Outgoing channel.
        :param event: Event.
        """
        # Create a bridge, putting both channels into it.
        bridge = client.bridges.create(type='mixing')
        outgoing.answer()
        bridge.addChannel(channel=[incoming.id, outgoing.id])
        # Clean up the bridge when done
        outgoing.on_event('StasisEnd', lambda *args: bridge.destroy())

    outgoing.on_event('StasisStart', outgoing_on_start)


client.on_channel_event('StasisStart', on_start)

# Run the WebSocket
client.run(apps="hello")
```

Why in some case it has used lambda as callback like in :

```
incoming.on_event('StasisEnd', lambda *args: safe_hangup(outgoing))
# and vice versa. If the endpoint rejects the call, it is destroyed
# without entering Stasis()
outgoing.on_event('ChannelDestroyed',
                  lambda *args: safe_hangup(incoming))
```

and in some case it doesn not use lambda like :

```
outgoing.on_event('StasisStart', outgoing_on_start)
```

Why is it using lambda in those cases ?Why we can not call the safe_hangup directly like the  outgoing_on_start?

Comment: `outgoing_on_start` will call `outgoing_on_start` and pass it whatever the `StasisStart` event passes as argument. `lambda *args: safe_hangup(outgoing)` will call `safe_hangup` and pass it `outgoing` as argument, discarding whatever argument the event passes in. — Does that clarify the difference?

Comment: That was what i got close to but could not safe_hangup be implemented so it could accept one positional argument and * args like safe_hangup(direction , * args)? was not this clearer ?

Comment: Then how do you pass `safe_hangup` to `on_event` while _also_ passing the `direction` argument?

Comment: Well i guess iam missing a point here . in fact i can not use safe_hangup(outgoing) as callback right ? what i can use is safe_hangup without parentheses, so it is not actually function exection rather callback declartion ?

Comment: Exactly. `safe_hangup` is a callback, but doesn't get any `direction` argument. `safe_hangup(outgoing)` isn't a callback, it's calling the function. `lambda *args: safe_hangup(outgoing)` is a callback that calls `safe_hungup` with the `direction` argument.

Comment: That cleared bunch of things @deceze, thank you.